# Installation of Haskell package hs_gchart fails ("Non type-variable argument in the constraint")

Tags: haskell

Trying to install the Haskell package hs_gchart, I got the error

```
"Non type-variable argument in the constraint: MonadState Chart m (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)"
```

in spite of allowing XFlexibleContexts in my call

```
stack install --ghc-options=-XFlexibleContexts hs-gchart
```

How can I solve the problem?

Output:

```
[...]
    [ 7 of 10] Compiling Graphics.GChart.ChartItems.Colors ( Graphics\GChart\ChartItems\Colors.hs, .stack-work\dist\7d103d30\build\Graphics\GChart\ChartItems\Colors.o )
    [ 8 of 10] Compiling Graphics.GChart.ChartItems.Basics ( Graphics\GChart\ChartItems\Basics.hs, .stack-work\dist\7d103d30\build\Graphics\GChart\ChartItems\Basics.o )
    [ 9 of 10] Compiling Graphics.GChart.ChartItems ( Graphics\GChart\ChartItems.hs, .stack-work\dist\7d103d30\build\Graphics\GChart\ChartItems.o )

[;1mGraphics\GChart\ChartItems.hs:62:1: [;1m[31merror:[0m[0m[;1m[0m[0m[;1m
    * Non type-variable argument in the constraint: MonadState Chart m
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type
        getDataSetIdx :: forall (m :: * -> *). MonadState Chart m => m Int[0m[0m
[;1m[34m   |[0m[0m
[;1m[34m62 |[0m[0m [;1m[31mgetDataSetIdx = do chart <- get[0m[0m
[;1m[34m   |[0m[0m[;1m[31m ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...[0m[0m
[0m[0m[0m
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved for me because I could install the package using a different package name:

stack install GoogleChart